# Unexplained linux panics or freezes

Tags: linux, freeze

Im having a hardware issue, where my arch linux box randomly becomes offline, and a reset is the only fix.

On the first reboot, i sometimes get a kernel panic message, where its left hanging

Here is two different times i have seen this, that i stopped to take a shot.
[image]
[image]
then on second reboot it always boots up.

```
$ uname -r
4.8.13-1-ARCH
```

Its happened across the last several kernel updates, not just this one.

I added a couple more hard drives, and suspected it was power issues, but after careful calculation the estimated 364 watts total should be covered by the 500w(max) power supply. Closest i could find to mine is here http://bit.ly/2hRvJjG but mine actually has a purple Okia sticker, on silver case, with model slightly different `Model:Okia-500WATX(500W Max)`with same specs as that, except also two combined specs:

> 230W max combined on the 3.3v+5v
>
> 422W max combined on the 3.3v + 5v + 12v

It is not until these hard drives are being fully written to for a duration (raidz2 stripe), then she goes offline.

Im not sure if i should just start pulling power on things, and retest things.

What i dont want to do is a bunch of unnecessary screwdriver/wire rerouting work.

Can i have some suggestions on maybe a diagnostic approach norm , or a troubleshooting technique, or something on how i should diagnose this the quickest?   It does involve a few parts, a pci, and a pci-e raid controller card, mobo, cpu,ps,**7 hd's**.  (Calculator still said 364W for all parts) Guess thats RMS?

Comment: **uname -r**   Which kernel version are you using?

Comment: Each voltage or grouped set of connectors comes with an individual separate maximum current / power. The 500 W sound pretty much like the total of you power supply. Did you check the details?

Comment: Almost certainly power.

Comment: @djsmiley2kk its good to hear you say that, and class slacker also taking about power, if its something else, im hating it, like mobo.. or what..

I updated the OP with the PSU details.

Comment: What is Combined Load 422W? is that Max or RMS?  or does this think just get thermo sensitive on cheap parts when you go over the 422W designed range?  I can see that happening.

Comment: I found that when the 6 drive array is being backed up to, is when the system just flat out restarts now, and this lands in a kernel panic message.  then after a reset there, things are fine (cause nothing is backing up, until i start it again)  Monitoring temps, i have 42-49Celsius on the 7 drives(one is system).  I can pretty much duplicate this diagnosis.    

So, is this looking like Inadequate power supply?  Im considering testing with 3 drives, is that a good test plan?  

Whoever stays on this, im going to ask they put the answer so i can up it, thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok, so this is on hold, until i get the new power supply, i narrrowed it all the way down to a separate power supply for the drives (two supplys), leaving old one still on board, and still problems, new PS on order.  ill update.  Thanks for help.